# Magento: Display all images on the product page (view.phtml)

Tags: magento

I can see how media.phtml (with Cloud Zoom extension) is listing all the images on the product page by help of $this->getGalleryImages():

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
<?php ... ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But when I use $this->getGalleryImages() in view.phtml which is the catalog product page template, it doesn't return or output anything. However, this would only print the first image on the product page:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->setWatermarkImageOpacity(0)->resize(300, null);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel());?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel());?>" />
```

My question is how can I iterate through and display all the product images on the product page (view.phtml, not media.phtml)? Basically, I want them all on display on the page without thumbnailing or zooming or anything, just plain big images, one after another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the code for showing product image gallery..

Thanks,
Jeet

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php if($_images){?>            
    <?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(108,90); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /><?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```